# Load detail table automatically - jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery Datatable that has a detail table, where it is displayed when expanded, the same as the [example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/row_details.html), but I need my detail table to display its detail table, but it can not be a click, it is displayed automatically.

I wonder if it is possible to make a call to the second detail table when loading the first detail table?

Every help is welcome

Table top:

```
$scope.loadTable = function () {

            $("#preloader").removeClass("ng-hide");
            $("#btnConsultar").attr("disabled", true);

            $scope.filtroExtrato.codigoSistemaUsuarios = $scope.user.codigoUsuario;

            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/sc/getExtrato',
                data: $scope.filtroExtrato
            }).then(function (response) {
                $scope.filtroExtrato.indicadorSalvarFiltro = false;
                tableExtrato(response.data);

                $("#preloader").addClass("ng-hide");
                $("#btnConsultar").attr("disabled", false);

            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);

                $("#preloader").addClass("ng-hide");
                $("#btnConsultar").attr("disabled", false);
            });


        };
```

Load data table top:

```
function tableExtrato(dados) {
            //Remover o manipulador de eventos de clique mais recente, adicionando .off antes de adicionar o novo
            $('#tableDocumentos tbody').off('click', 'td.details-control');

            var table = $('#tableDocumentos').DataTable({

                aaData: dados,

                language: {
                    url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json",
                    decimal: ",",
                    thousands: "."
                },
                deferRender: true,
                bAutoWidth: false,
                bProcessing: true,
                bDeferRender: true,

                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                    visible: false
                }],


                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: {
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extends: "text",
                            text: "<i class='fa fa-expand' tooltip-placement='top' tooltip='Expandir/Recolher'/>",
                            className: "btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-round mr5",
                            action: function (button, config) {
                                $('#tableDocumentos tbody td:first-child').trigger('click');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            extend: 'print',
                            className: "btn btn-warning btn-outline btn-round",
                            text: "<i class='fa fa-print' tooltip-placement='top' tooltip='Imprimir'/>",
                            title: "Sistema Colaborativo - Extrato Financeiro",
                            exportOptions: {
                                columns: ':visible'
                            },
                            action: function (e, dt, button, config) {
                                /* true here means table has child rows */
                                dt_print(e, dt, button, config, true)
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    dom: {
                        container: {
                            className: 'dt-buttons'
                        },
                        button: {
                            className: 'btn btn-default'
                        }
                    }
                },


                sAjaxDataProp: "",
                bDestroy: true,
                order: [[3, "asc"]],
                columns: [
                    {
                        /*
                         * column exists for purpose of printing/exporting
                         * only required when using child rows
                         */
                        title: 'index',
                        visible: false,
                        render: function (row, type, full, meta) {
                            return meta.row;
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        className: 'details-control',
                        orderable: false,
                        data: null,
                        defaultContent: '',
                        width: "1%"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "pessoaCnpj", width: "13%"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoDataEmissao", type: "date", width: "8%", render: function (data) {
                        if (data !== null) {
                            var javascriptDate = new Date(data);
                            var day = javascriptDate.getDate().toString();
                            day = ('00' + day).substring(day.length);
                            var month = (javascriptDate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
                            month = ('00' + month).substring(month.length);
                            var year = javascriptDate.getFullYear().toString();
                            javascriptDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                            return javascriptDate;
                        } else {
                            return "";
                        }
                    }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoDigitado", width: "12%", orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoTipo", width: "10%", orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoValorLiquido",
                        "type": "decimal",
                        "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2),
                        width: "8%",
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoValorBaixado",
                        type: "decimal",
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2),
                        width: "8%",
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoValorSaldo",
                        type: "decimal",
                        render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2),
                        width: "8%",
                        orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoTotalParcelas", width: "8%", orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoSituacao", width: "8%"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "filialNome", width: "15%", orderable: false
                    },
                    {
                        data: "documentoHistorico", width: "15%", orderable: false
                    },
                ],


            });

            //Define quais as colunas serão visiveis para o usuário conforme o filtro
            if ($scope.filtroExtrato.colunasDataTable.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; $scope.filtroExtrato.colunasDataTable.length > i; i++) {
                    table.column($scope.filtroExtrato.colunasDataTable[i]).visible(true);
                }
            }

            $('#tableDocumentos tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
                var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                var row = table.row(tr);

                if (row.child.isShown()) {
                    // This row is already open - close it
                    row.child.hide();
                    tr.removeClass('shown');
                }
                else {
                    // Open this row
                    var htmlChild = tableParcelas(row.data());
                    row.child(htmlChild).show();
                    tr.addClass('shown');

                }
            });
        }
```

Table Detail

```
function tableParcelas(d) {
            $("#preloader").removeClass("ng-hide");

            $http({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/sc/getExtratoParcelas',
                data: d.codigoFinanceirofndocumentos
            }).then(function (response) {
                var tableParcelas = $('#tableParcelas_' + d.codigoFinanceirofndocumentos.toString()).DataTable({

                    aaData: response.data,

                    language: {
                        url: "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Portuguese-Brasil.json",
                        decimal: ",",
                        thousands: "."
                    },
                    bPaginate: false,
                    info: false,
                    paging: false,
                    searching: false,
                    bAutoWidth: false,
                    bProcessing: true,
                    bDeferRender: true,
                    sAjaxDataProp: "",
                    bDestroy: true,
                    order: [[3, "asc"]],
                    columns: [
                        {data: "parcelaDocumentoDigitado", width: "8%", orderable: false},
                        {data: "parcelaTipoParcela", width: "13%", orderable: false},
                        {data: "parcelaAp", width: "13%", orderable: false},
                        {
                            data: "parcelaDataVencimento", type: "date", width: "8%", render: function (data) {
                            if (data !== null) {
                                var javascriptDate = new Date(data);
                                var day = javascriptDate.getDate().toString();
                                day = ('00' + day).substring(day.length);
                                var month = (javascriptDate.getMonth() + 1).toString();
                                month = ('00' + month).substring(month.length);
                                var year = javascriptDate.getFullYear().toString();
                                javascriptDate = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
                                return javascriptDate;
                            } else {
                                return "";
                            }
                        }
                        },
                        {
                            data: "parcelaValorTotal",
                            "type": "decimal",
                            "render": $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2),
                            width: "8%",
                            orderable: false
                        },
                        {
                            data: "parcelaValorBaixado",
                            type: "decimal",
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2),
                            width: "8%",
                            orderable: false
                        },
                        {
                            data: "parcelaSaldo",
                            type: "decimal",
                            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number('.', ',', 2),
                            width: "8%",
                            orderable: false
                        },
                        {data: "parcelaSituacao", width: "10%", orderable: false}

                    ]
                });

                $("#preloader").addClass("ng-hide");
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);

                $("#preloader").addClass("ng-hide");
            });


            // `d` is the original data object for the row
            var html =
                '<div class="panel mb25"> ' +
                '<div class="panel-heading border"> ' +
                'Parcelas ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '<div class="panel-body"> ' +
                '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-xs-12 mb25">' +
                '<div class="no-more-tables "> ' +
                '<table id="tableParcelas_' + d.codigoFinanceirofndocumentos.toString() + '" cellspacing="0" width="100%" ' +
                'class="table table-striped table-condensed datatable table-striped mb0"> ' +
                '<thead> ' +
                '<tr style="background: #3276B1; color: #ffffff"> ' +
                '<th>Parcela</th> ' +
                '<th>Tipo Parcela</th> ' +
                '<th>AP</th> ' +
                '<th>Vencimento</th> ' +
                '<th>Total</th> ' +
                '<th>Baixado</th> ' +
                '<th>Saldo</th> ' +
                '<th>Situação</th> ' +
                '</tr> ' +
                '</thead> ' +
                '</table> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div> ' +
                '</div>';

            if ($scope.filtroExtrato.indicadorLogistico) {
                html = html + tableInformacoesLogisticas(d);
            }

            return html;

        }
```

Comment: Please add your code. It help others understand more your issue.

Comment: Do you want this functionality [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dhardin/omny3erh/) ?

Comment: My detail table is not a continuation of my main table, but a new call to ajax with new data according to the Id of that row of the main table, so this example I can not use, unfortunately. Any other suggestions?